# Whitelist IP addresses for access to AWS S3 static web hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting

I have seen several references that use a Bucket Policy similar in structure to the following

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1607646663558",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1607646606566",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "73.63.x.y",
                        "73.63.w.x"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In addition as part of debugging this I have left it open to the world . That's not preferable and it would be nice to tighten that up.

[image]

But even with that open it is not working (I am accessing from the 73.63.x.y ip address)

[image]

Two questions:

- Why is this permission denied for a whitelisted IP?
- Is it possible to enable the "Block all public access" and still get through via the whitelisted IP's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add /32 to your IP address if you are allowing a host (like this 73.63.x.y/32) or the corresponding netmask for a block of IPs.

Tge answers to your questions:

- The permission (effect) is deny because your condition is `NotIpAddress`.
- Yes, because AWS evaluates all policies. User policies, and resource-based policies (bucket policy, bucket ACL, object ACL) to decide on the allow or deny.

Comment: Your first bullet seems incorrect because it's  `Deny | NotIpAddress` which is a  double negative. This is a common pattern.     I do not understand your second bullet point answer; pls elaborate.

Comment: What you call a double negative is what makes a whitelist. You are denying access to all IP addresses that don't match the list of IPs you listed. So you are allowing only the listed IPs. Your IP addresses need to look like 73.63.x.y/32 not just the IP address (without/32).

Comment: Ah ok will add the `/32`

Comment: For the second bullet, I meant that you can "Block all public access" and still access your files/objects when you set your bucket policy correctly, because AWS evaluates all policies (user and resource). The resulting permissions are the intersection.

Comment: "intersection" indicates both policies need to be satisfied - which is different than the apparent intent of your last comment that reads like "union".  I do not know the answer to this but am confused by the wording

Comment: Please check this out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/images/PolicyEvaluationHorizontal.png